# Intuition for Integration and Starting Points

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, soft-question

I've been learning about all the different integration tricks lately, and I'm wondering what your thinking process is when you encounter a new problem.

For example, say we need to simplify$$I=\int\limits_0^a dx\,\frac {\log x}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}$$The way to go is to notice how replacing $x$ with $a-x$ in the radicand reduces to the same expression. So$$I=\int\limits_0^adx\frac {\log(a-x)}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}=\int\limits_0^adx\frac {\log(ax-x^2)}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}$$And adding the two expressions together gives you a nice integral which can be evaluated much easily. However, I'm stuck on **how you come up with the idea in the first place**. I'm having trouble with finding a good place to start when I encounter these kinds of problems.

Another example is with$$\int\limits_0^1dx\,\log\left(\frac {1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac 1{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac {\pi^2}2$$If you make a substitution$$t=\frac {1+x}{1-x}\quad\implies\quad x=\frac {1-t}{1+t}$$Then the problem reduces to another problem which can be solved using substitution. However, I'm having trouble understanding how you come up with the substitution for $t$ in the first place.

> **Question:**
>
> 1. What goes through your mind when you're integrating an expression you've never encountered before?
> 2. What are a few useful tricks in integration that may help?

I'm sorry if this post was a bit vague or hard to understand. I'm having a hard time grasping it and putting it into simple, legible English.

Comment: Integration by parts is always a good thing to keep in mind

Comment: Look for symmetries. Changes of variable are often hinted by the integrand itself (pick some term in the expression and make it simpler). You should practice the changes of variable to be able to predict their effect.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^a \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}} \, dx = \int_0^a \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x(a-x)}} \,dx
$$

The number $x$ is the distance from the left endpoint of the interval $[0,a],$ and $a-x$ is the distance from the right enpoint, and that is the interval over which one integrates.

Letting $y = {}$distance from the right endpoint and $a-y={}$distance from the left endpoint, you have the same expression in the denominator since you're just multiplying both distances, and going from one endpoint to the other you have $y$ going from $0$ to $a.$ (You have $dy = -dx,$ and $y$ goes from $a$ down to $0$ as $x$ goes from $0$ up to $a,$ but then the minus sign vanishes when you change $\int_a^0$ to $\int_0^a.$ And you get
$$
\int_0^a \frac{\log(a-y)}{\sqrt{ay-y^2}} \,dy
$$
and that is of course
$$
\int_0^a \frac{\log(a-x)}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}} \, dx.
$$
You misplaced an "equals" sign when you said that is equal to $\displaystyle \int_0^a \frac{\log(ax-x^2)}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}\,dx.$ Those are not equal; rather the sum of the two integrals is equal to that.

The beta distribution is the probability distribution with density $\text{constant} \times x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1},$ and its expected value is $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta),$ and in doing various things with that integral, one should remember that $x$ and $1-x$ are both distances from opposite endpoints, so they're both the same kind of thing; there's a symmetry here.

As far as how you think of things like this in the first place, unfortunately with integrals, unlike derivatives, there's no algorithmic rule.